# C# check if number exists in array

Tags: c#

I am trying to ask user to enter 10 numbers and store them into the array. Then prompt the user to enter any number to check if the number already stored in the array. The screen will go away when I enter any number, which I cant validate if the number already exist. Please look at my codes. Thanks in advance.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] numCheck = new int[10];
        int[] userInput = new int[1];

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter 10 numbers: ");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Number {0}: ", i + 1);
            numCheck[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter any number to check if the number already exist");

        for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++)
        {
            if (userInput == numCheck)
            {
                Console.Write("The number {0} is in the index", numCheck);
                userInput[j] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            else 
            {
                Console.Write("The number {} is not in the index", numCheck);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Might want to check out the Array.Contains function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384015(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested alternative:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] numCheck = new int[10];
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter 10 numbers: ");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Number {0}: ", i + 1);
        numCheck[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter any number to check if the number already exist");
    int userInput = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (userInput == numCheck[i])
        {
            Console.Write("FOUND NUMBER");

            break;
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You only take 1 item from user so no need to declare an array

```
int userInput;

//read userInput

if (numCheck.Any(i => i == userInput))
{
    Console.Write("The number {0} is in the index", userInput);
}
else
{
    Console.Write("The number {} is not in the index", userInput);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't this:

```
if (userInput == numCheck)
```

Be:

```
if (userInput[0] == numCheck[j])
```